# How to determine Carrier Aggregation Class

Tags: lte

We see classes defined for Carrier Aggregation. The number of continuous carrier determines which class of CA it is.

- what are the criteria to decide contiguous carriers?
- Do the carriers need to stick with each other with no gaps? Or can some gaps of MHz be used as well?
- If the gap can be used, does it also contribute to the overall BW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what are the criteria to decide contiguous carriers?

the amount of spectrum that a mobile network operator owns, the amount of data you want to transmit, and a commercially-motivated decision by the network to combine multiple component carriers for you.

So, all in all, not a signal processing, but a system and spectrum utilization  as well as a financial question.

> Do the carriers need to stick with each other with no gaps? Or can some gaps of MHz be used as well?

The carriers aggregated can be non-contiguous.

> If the gap can be used, does it also contribute to the overall BW?

That fully depends on how **you** define "bandwidth".

Comment: Thanks. I am interested to know about how to determine whether contiguous or not. Suppose I have a carrier of BW 10 MHz and other carrier of BW 5 MHz, the separation between edge end of first carrier and edge start of second carrier is 10 MHz, both carrier belonging to same band X, will my configuration be BXA_BXA or BXB (10+5) or BXC (10+10+5)

Comment: I don't understand your notation, sorry. Also, this really seems to be a question of "how is my mobile network operator configuring things", not something anyone else could answer.